# How can I use parameter in useQuery() as 'DocumentNode' in Apollo?

Tags: react-hooks, apollo, react-apollo, gql

I would like to have a generic `useQuery()` hook where the `DocumentNode`’s value defined elsewhere:
one `useQuery()` with `animal` parameter to get dogs or cats depended on value of `animal`.

Something like:

```
let ANIMAL= ‘GET_CATS’

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery({ANIMAL});
```

with `gql` definition of:

```
const GET_DOGS = gql`
  {
    dogs {
      id
      breed
    }
  }
`;

const GET_CATS = gql`
  {
    cats {
      id
      breed
    }
  }
`;
```